# PG Admin III Slony-I creation scripts not available

Tags: windows, postgresql, pgadmin, slony

I have installed PostgreSQL 9.4 (x86),  PG Admin 1.20 and Slony-I 2.2.3 through Stack Builder on a windows platform.
When trying to create a new Slony cluster in pgAdmin, I get the 
"Slony-I creation scripts not available" error message.

1) I have setup options Slony-I path to 
-->:C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.4\share

where all the slony1_*.sql scripts are located but I still get the same error.

2) Using procmon I see that PGAdmin tries to access 
"slony1_funcs.sql" and "slony1_funcs.2.2.0.sql" none of which exist in my \share directory

the installed funcs scripts are "slony1_funcs.2.2.3.sql", "slony1_funcs.v83.2.2.3.sql", slony1_funcs.v84.2.2.3.sql
and the base scripts are "slony1_base.2.2.3.sql", "slony1_base.v83.2.2.3.sql", slony1_base.v84.2.2.3.sql

3) I have tried to rename "slony1_funcs.2.2.3.sql" to "slony1_funcs.2.2.0.sql" and "slony1_funcs.sql" and I now get a new error "Couldn't test for the Slony version. Assuming 1.2.0" and again the 
"Slony-I creation scripts not available" error message

Does anyone have an idea how to get this working?